# XCode 4.x do not include Perl MakeMaker. brew failed - Asks for Perl file. 

Tags: macos, perl, homebrew, xcode4.3, makemaker

I am trying to install node.js following instructions.
Just installed Homebrew. I tried this.

```
 brew install git -v
```

But get this error message: make[2]: *** No rule to make target '...config.h', needed by `perl.mak'.  Stop.

It asks for my config.h file in '/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE' but the files i find there are only 'libperl.dylib' and 'perl.h'. Perhaps the reason is that I use 10.6 instead of 10.7? I installed command line tools for Xcode for Lion.

Same issue. [git does not install on Lion.](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7091) There [a fix was published](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/6f4b710). But I can't understand how it helps me.  The fix:

```
 
+    # Clean XCode 4.x installs don't include Perl MakeMaker
     32 
+    ENV['NO_PERL_MAKEMAKER']='1' if MacOS.lion?
     33 
+
```

My command line:

```
==> Downloading http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.10.tar.gz

... (text I removed)

rm -f git-add--interactive git-add--interactive+ && \
    INSTLIBDIR=`MAKEFLAGS= make -C perl -s --no-print-directory instlibdir` && \
    sed -e '1{' \
        -e '    s|#!.*perl|#!/usr/bin/perl|' \
        -e '    h' \
        -e '    s=.*=use lib (split(/:/, $ENV{GITPERLLIB} || "'"$INSTLIBDIR"'"));=' \
        -e '    H' \
        -e '    x' \
        -e '}' \
        -e 's/@@GIT_VERSION@@/1.7.10/g' \
        git-add--interactive.perl >git-add--interactive+ && \
    chmod +x git-add--interactive+ && \
    mv git-add--interactive+ git-add--interactive
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/config.h', needed by `perl.mak'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [instlibdir] Error 2
make: *** [git-add--interactive] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
==> Exit Status: 2
https://github.com/mxcl/master/blob/master/Library/Formula/git.rb#L49
==> Build Environment
CPU: dual-core 64-bit penryn
MacOS: 10.6.8-i386
Xcode: 4.3
MacPorts/Fink: /sw/bin/fink
CC: /usr/bin/clang
CXX: /usr/bin/clang++ => /usr/bin/clang
LD: /usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments
CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments
MAKEFLAGS: -j2
Error: Failed executing: make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.10 CC=/usr/bin/clang CFLAGS=-Os\ -w\ -pipe\ -march=native\ -Qunused-arguments LDFLAGS= install (git.rb:49)
```

Comment: To downvoter: Since homebrew do not seem to have a 'help mailinglist' or something. I see no better option than posting here.

Comment: This is why you should install your own perl and pretend the system doesn't have one.

Comment: Yes. I have just figured it out. Now installing 5.14. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install your own Perl. Follow [these instructions](http://blogs.perl.org/users/peter_edwards/2011/06/installing-local-perl-and-libraries-on-mac-book-snow-leopard.html) for 10.6 Snow leopard.